# Conectar Base de datos a ventana de registro Java

Tags: java

Tengo esta ventana `VentanRegistro`, en la cual se podrán realizar los ingresos de los datos para una universidad (Ficticia), he visto tutoriales para conectar mi programa a una base de datos pero, todos explican la conectividad realizada con un "Formulario" en Java pero, yo lo realicé de esta forma y quiero aprender cómo poder conectarla de igual manera.

```
package alumnos;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class VentanaRegistro extends JFrame{
    
    public JPanel panel;
    
    public VentanaRegistro(){
        
        setTitle("Alumnos");
        setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
        IniciarComponentes();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    private void IniciarComponentes(){
        ColocarPaneles();
        ColocarEtiquetas();
        ColocarBotones();
        CajasTexto();
    }
    
    private void ColocarPaneles(){
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        
        panel.setLayout(null);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    }
    
    private void ColocarEtiquetas(){
                
        JLabel etiqueta1 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta1.setText("Registro Alumnos");
        etiqueta1.setBounds(350, 20, 700, 70);
        etiqueta1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        etiqueta1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta1.setOpaque(true);
        etiqueta1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        etiqueta1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,50));
        panel.add(etiqueta1);
        
        JLabel etiqueta2 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta2.setText("Nombre completo");
        etiqueta2.setBounds(35, 120, 600, 70);
        etiqueta2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
        
        panel.add(etiqueta2);
        
        JLabel etiqueta3 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta3.setText("DNI");
        etiqueta3.setBounds(35, 250, 600, 70);
        etiqueta3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta3.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
        
        panel.add(etiqueta3);
        
        JLabel etiqueta4 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta4.setText("CUIL");
        etiqueta4.setBounds(35, 370, 600, 70);
        etiqueta4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta4.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
        
        panel.add(etiqueta4);
                        
        JLabel etiqueta5 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta5.setText("Edad");
        etiqueta5.setBounds(35, 510, 600, 70);
        etiqueta5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta5.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
        
        panel.add(etiqueta5);
        
        JLabel etiqueta6 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta6.setText("Año de Ingreso");
        etiqueta6.setBounds(535, 120, 600, 70);
        etiqueta6.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta6.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
        
        panel.add(etiqueta6);
        
        JLabel etiqueta7 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta7.setText("Año de Egreso");
        etiqueta7.setBounds(535, 250, 600, 70);
        etiqueta7.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta7.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
        
        panel.add(etiqueta7);
        
        JLabel etiqueta8 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta8.setText("Promedio");
        etiqueta8.setBounds(535, 370, 600, 70);
        etiqueta8.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta8.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
       
        panel.add(etiqueta8);
        
        JLabel etiqueta9 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta9.setText("Carrera que cursa");
        etiqueta9.setBounds(535, 510, 600, 70);
        etiqueta9.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta9.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
       
        panel.add(etiqueta9);
                
        JLabel etiqueta10 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta10.setText("Reingreso a la universidad");
        etiqueta10.setBounds(1035, 120, 600, 70);
        etiqueta10.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta10.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
        
        panel.add(etiqueta10);
        
        JLabel etiqueta11 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta11.setText("Institución donde estudió anteriormente");
        etiqueta11.setBounds(1035, 250, 600, 70);
        etiqueta11.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta11.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
        
        panel.add(etiqueta11);
        
        JLabel etiqueta12 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta12.setText("Registro económico");
        etiqueta12.setBounds(1035, 370, 600, 70);
        etiqueta12.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta12.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
       
        panel.add(etiqueta12);
        
        JLabel etiqueta13 = new JLabel();
        
        etiqueta13.setText("Cantidad de Materias aprobadas");
        etiqueta13.setBounds(1035, 510, 600, 70);
        etiqueta13.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        etiqueta13.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.HANGING_BASELINE,20));
       
        panel.add(etiqueta13);
    }
```

Acá es donde se encuentran los botones y en particular el botón de enviar pero, no sé cómo hacer que este envíe los datos que ingreso en las cajas de abajo a la base de datos local realizada con XAMPP

```
    private void ColocarBotones(){
        
        JButton boton1 = new JButton();
        
        boton1.setText("Enviar");
        boton1.setBounds(35, 700, 250, 50);
        boton1.setFont(new Font("Arial",3,20));
        
        panel.add(boton1);
        
        JButton boton2 = new JButton();
        
        boton2.setText("Salir");
        boton2.setBounds(1085, 700, 250, 50);
        boton2.setFont(new Font("Arial",3,20));
        [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
        panel.add(boton2);
                      
        ActionListener salida = new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if(ae.getSource() == boton2){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        };
        
        boton2.addActionListener(salida);
        
        JButton boton3 = new JButton();
        
        boton3.setText("Menú");
        boton3.setBounds(560, 700, 250, 50);
        boton3.setFont(new Font("Arial",3,20));
        
            boton3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {                
                if(ae.getSource()==boton3){
                Ventana v = new Ventana();
                    v.setVisible(true);
                    dispose();
                }
            }
        });
                
        panel.add(boton3);
    }
```

**Estas son las cajas**

```
    public void CajasTexto(){
        
        JTextField caja1 = new JTextField();
        
        caja1.setBounds(35, 210, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja1);
        
        JTextField caja2 = new JTextField();
        
        caja2.setBounds(35, 340, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja2);
        
        JTextField caja3 = new JTextField();
        
        caja3.setBounds(35, 470, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja3);
        
        JTextField caja4 = new JTextField();
        
        caja4.setBounds(35, 600, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja4);
                
        JTextField caja5 = new JTextField();
        
        caja5.setBounds(535, 210, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja5);
        
        JTextField caja6 = new JTextField();
        
        caja6.setBounds(535, 340, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja6);
        
        JTextField caja7 = new JTextField();
        
        caja7.setBounds(535, 470, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja7);
        
        JTextField caja8 = new JTextField();
        
        caja8.setBounds(535, 600, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja8);
                        
        JTextField caja9 = new JTextField();
        
        caja9.setBounds(1035, 210, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja9);
        
        JTextField caja10 = new JTextField();
        
        caja10.setBounds(1035, 340, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja10);
        
        JTextField caja11 = new JTextField();
        
        caja11.setBounds(1035, 470, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja11);
        
        JTextField caja12 = new JTextField();
        
        caja12.setBounds(1035, 600, 300, 30);
        
        panel.add(caja12);
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltaria que crees una clase encargada de realizar la conexion con la base de datos,podrias utilizar jdbc driver pero faltaria que especifiques que base de datos estas utilizando o piensas utilizar.

Comment: bien, ¿Cómo hago para que el botón acceda a esa clase y cumpla esas funciones? ¿Esa clase tiene que ser un main también o no hace falta?